# Using MATCH(FILTER) AGAINST with LIKE mysql

Tags: mysql, string, match, match-against

i will try to describe my question  as simple as possible

i have a table called FILTERS with 2 columns 'Filter' and 'ID'

this table is populated like below example

```
|_. Filter |_. ID|
| shoes| 1|
| black shoe| 0|
| bot shoe| 3|
| bots | 2|
```

and

search string is ' i am looking for shoes and bots '

```
SELECT * from Filters WHERE match(Filter) AGAINST ('i am looking for shoes and bots')
```

getting nothing as a query result...but i want to get the query result ID 3 which filter column contains bot shoe

when i change the search string to  'i am looking for shoe and bot'

i get id 3 and 0

i tried to add IN BOOLEAN MODE and '+' for each words i am searching ... didnt help though

```
SELECT * from Filters WHERE match(Filter) AGAINST ('i am looking for +shoes and +bots' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your table, the query with `'i am looking for shoes and bots'` returns 1 and 2, the query with `'i am looking for shoe and bot'` returns 1,3.
The one with BOOLEAN MOD returns nothing because none of the rows contains both `shoes` and `bots`.
It looks correct to me.
How did you create your FULLTEXT index?

Comment: *getting nothing as a query result* Not reproduced: https://dbfiddle.uk/OYblP-ch

Comment: @ringunger also i want to get id 3 from the string 'i am looking for shoes and bots'  along with id  1 and 2

Comment: Try `i am looking for shoe* and bot*`

Comment: nope this not what i want..because i dont have any control over the search string to remove char(s) from the words which i will never know what char i have to remove...basically i can add anything but removing. so 'i am looking for shoes* and bots*' wont work.